# read ill formated json

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a giant (1.4G) JSON that seems ill formed. This is a toy example:

```
{"text": {"hello": "world"}, "ints": [1,2,3,4]},{"text": {"hola": "mundo"}, "ints": [5,6,7,8]}...
```

Where basically each dictionary is separated by a comma, but their not in a list format that would allow me to read it with something like `json.load`.
I've tried things like turn it into a .txt file and then read that, so I can make it work within python, but this approach makes my machine run out of memory (it's a 32g machine)

```
with open('bad_json.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
test_json = json.loads(list(eval(lines[0])))
```

Any thoughts on how to do this without crashing my machine?
Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't putting them in a list format be an easy solution?

Comment: sure @StrangeSorcerer, but how? doing `list(eval(lines[0]))` does that, but it makes my machine run out of memory

Comment: Couldn't you add it manually? add a `[` at the start and `]` at the end of the the JSON value.

Comment: I also tried that and it fails for the same out of memory reasons